# How to compare words in a .txt file to an array and record the index in another array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, import

I have this text file that is tab separated with about 1,000 columns and 12,000 rows when pasted into an excel spreadsheet. My goal is to have some way where I can compare an array of strings

```
arWords = Array("Title1", "Title2", "Title3")
```

To the column headers in that .txt file. When a match is found i would like to know what "column" that word was found in, and put it in another array. In this example it would be an array of 3 integers each one representing which column each Title was found. My goal is to end up with an array that looks like this.

```
listIndex = array(159, 393, 400)
```

And if i include 4 Titles in arWords, then i will end up with an array of 4 integers representing their column #.
Here is my code, its not good im very bad at this, but thanks nonetheless!

```
Const ForReading = 1
Dim FSO, FileIn, strTmp

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FileIn = FSO.OpenTextFile(movietitles.txt, ForReading)


arWords = Array("Title1", "Title2", "Title3")
size = UBound(arWords) - LBound(arWords) + 1
Dim listIndex() As Integer
ReDim listIndex(size)

Do Until FileIn.AtEndOfStream
    strTmp = FileIn.ReadLine
    If Len(strTmp) > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(arWords)
            If InStr(1, strTmp, arWords(i), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                listIndex(i) = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
Loop

FileIn.Close
     

    ReDim yArray(1 To lColumn)
    Dim Counter As Integer
       For Counter = 1 To lColumn
            yArray(Counter) = 9
        Next Counter
        
    For Each Index In listIndex
        yArray(Index) = 1
    Next Index
```

Comment: Should that `movietitles.txt` be the text file where to search for the strings array? If yes, it must contain the path, too and everything be between double quotes. Now, is the header in discussion in the first row of the text file?

Comment: Hi! Ah yes i have the path in the code as well. The way the text file is set up is weird. So when i copy and past the data in excel, there are about 200 rows in the first column with random data. The rest of the columns for those 200 rows are empty. Beginning on row 201 though begin the headers which go on to about 1000 columns and the rest of the 11,800 rows (Under the headers is just data (numbers))

Comment: I did  not understand anything from your "clarification" comment, sorry... So, in which row are the headers where the string array elements to be searched? What relevance to have "200 rows in the first column"? Should I translate in the next way? Yes, the headers are in the first row, but there are a lot of empty columns up to the limit of 1000 (or more). Should this understanding be correct? If not, please try clarifying this aspect. Basically, in which row are the headers? Or a logic to determine this row, if not the first...

Comment: So, should the header row be 201?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumption after reading your comment is correct, please try the next code. I assumed that the header is on the first row of the text file. No need to open it in Excel:

```
Sub MatchStringArrayToHeaders()
   Dim fileName As String, arWords, arrTxt, arrH, arrFin, El, mtch
   Dim k As Long, headRow As Long i As Long
   fileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\MyTestFile.txt" 'use here your text file full name
   
   arWords = Array("Title1", "Title2", "Title3")
   ReDim arrFin(UBound(arWords)) 'redim the final array to be returned
   'put all the text file content in an array of rows:
   arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fileName, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
   
   'find the header row: __________________________
   For i = 0 To UBound(arrTxt)
      arrH = Split(arrTxt(i), vbTab)
      If UBound(arrH) > 0 Then
        If arrH(1) <> "" Then HeaderRow = i: Exit For
      End If
   Next i
   '_______________________________________________
   arrH = Split(arrTxt(headRow), vbTab)
   
   For Each El In arWords
        mtch = Application.match(El, arrH, 0) 'return the matching header number
        If IsNumeric(mtch) Then               'if a match could be found
            arrFin(k) = mtch: k = k + 1       'put the column number in the final array
        Else
            'if not any match, write in Immediate Window the not matching string
            Debug.Print El & " could not be found in the headers row..."
        End If
   Next
   'Only to visually check the returned array:
   Debug.Print Join(arrFin, "|") 'the obtained array is joined using "|" separator and returned in Immediate Window (`Ctrl + G`, being in VBE).
End Sub
```

If the headers row is not all the time the same, please give me the column 1 marker for this header row and I will adapt the code to firstly search for this marker, set the headers row and use it...

Comment: Thanks for replying @FaneDuru! Works like a charm! Only thing is though it isnt able to sort through the first column. Im sorry for the bad explanation. Basically the data when pasted into excel looks like the shape of an "L". 
The first column is longer than the rest. It usually will change so this time theres 200 rows in the first column before the headers appear, whereas next time the data file might have 210 rows in the first column before headers begin populating.

Comment: how can i automate it so it know which row to start reading basically.

Comment: @kyle Not sure I've got you... Does your question contain something about some "sorting" and I missed it? I only understood "My goal is to end up with an array that looks like this" and my code answers this question as is was formulated. I asked clarification questions but no clarifications received... Like I told you, finding the headers row is not something able to **solve any kind of file**. I said: "give me the column 1 marker", in order to do it. So, If I would understand that that **the first row not having an empty string in its first column is the headers row**, will it be correct?

Comment: Its ok ill figure it out, you've helped more than enough. Thanks again!

Comment: @kyle I am afraid you did not understand me... I like helping people, but if I am able to understand what they need. Can you better explain how that headers row should be found? I mean, **based on what**... Is my above supposition wrong? The one involving the first row not having an empty cell in its first column...

Comment: I am thinking of a way how to find the headers row. Only way I can find where the headers begin is when the rest of the columns have data in it. For the first 200 rows in column A, Columns B-ZZ have nothing in them. In row 201 column A, Columns B-ZZ Have data in it. The first row for data to be present in All columns is the header row.

Comment: @kyle OK. I will try adapting the code to search for the first not empty cell in the second column...

Comment: @kyle please, test the adapted code, which should detect the headers row, as the first one having a not empty string in the second column.

Comment: Hey @FaneDuru, i tried running it and it gives me 'subscript out of range' and it highlights `if arrH(1) <> "" Then` as the culprit

Comment: @kyle It is difficult to understand what happens without knowing anything about the file to be processed... Is it possible that the first rows to not have empty cells in second column, **but only a cell in the first one**? Can you share the file you try processing? If my previous supposition is correct, I will try adapting the code to firstly check the array number of elements. The error suggests that there is no second element in the array...

Comment: Please, check the updated code and send some feedback. If it still does not work, please share the file. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) it is a free transfer site, easy to be used...

Comment: What should i change if it should search for the first empty cell in the 4th column?

Comment: @kyle So, it looks that I was right... Glad I could help! But you must learn that when ask a question you must try putting in shoes of the one trying to help and think somehow like you will be him. If you do not help me to help you, the helping process doesn't work, or works consuming more resources than it should... :)